# Spec of the ring of holomorphic functions on a complex  manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, and let $O(X)$ be the ring of holomorphic functions on $X$ .

Is there any important relation between the locally ringed spaces $(\operatorname{Spec}(
O(X)),O_{\operatorname{Spec}(O(X)})$ and $(X,O)$, where $O$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on U ?

Comment: It's always just a point, so my guess is no.

Comment: of course, you're both right, in the case when the complex manifold is compact and connected it becomes trivial. I made an edition, I delete the projective part.

Comment: Edit the title too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spec construction has the following property: there is a natural bijection
$$\textbf{LocRingSp}(X, \operatorname{Spec} A) \cong \textbf{CRing}(A, \mathscr{O}(X))$$
Hence, there is always a morphism $X \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathscr{O}(X)$. Moreover, for *any* ring $B$ and any morphism $X \to \operatorname{Spec} B$, there is a unique factorisation through $\operatorname{Spec} \mathscr{O}(X)$. So you can think of $\operatorname{Spec} \mathscr{O}(X)$ as being the universal affine scheme which approximates $X$.

The case where $X$ is a connected complex projective manifold is somewhat uninteresting though: $\mathscr{O}(X)$ is just the ring of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, and $\operatorname{Spec} \mathscr{O}(X)$ is just a point. Perhaps you should be asking about *relative* Spec?